# Failed to install pg 1.4.6 with native extensions using Postgres.app on MacOSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

I am trying to run `rails s` but encounter a failure when installing the pg gem for use with Postgres.app on my local machine. I am running Ventura.

Postgres.app is installed and running fine, but I cannot get the pg gem to work. I've done the following:

- Installed the [Postgres App](https://postgresapp.com/) according to the docs.
- Used the command 'env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config' from the Postgres.app documentation
- Updated and Upgraded Homebrew
- Installed the Xcode developer tools

Updated my $PATH to reference both the Postgres.app bin and lib directories stored in my .zshrc file

**zshrc file**

```
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"

export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"


export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"

  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Issue is persisting we running `bundle` or `bundle install`

```
$ bundle     
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using minitest 5.16.3
Using builder 3.2.4
Using racc 1.6.1
Using erubi 1.11.0
Using date 3.3.1
Using rack 2.2.4
Using ansi 1.5.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using msgpack 1.6.0
Using byebug 11.1.3
Using io-console 0.5.11
Using mini_mime 1.1.2
Using coderay 1.1.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Using timeout 0.3.1
Using diff-lcs 1.5.0
Using thor 1.2.1
Using rspec-support 3.12.0
Using marcel 1.0.2
Using i18n 1.12.0
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using ruby-progressbar 1.13.0
Using tzinfo 2.0.5
Using bundler 2.3.26
Using reline 0.3.1
Using nokogiri 1.13.10 (arm64-darwin)
Using net-protocol 0.2.1
Using rspec-core 3.12.1
Using rack-test 2.0.2
Using rspec-expectations 3.12.2
Using nio4r 2.5.8
Using zeitwerk 2.6.6
Using websocket-driver 0.7.5
Using rspec-mocks 3.12.4
Using pry 0.14.2
Using minitest-reporters 1.6.0
Using bootsnap 1.15.0
Using activesupport 7.0.4
Using irb 1.6.1
Using puma 5.6.5
Using loofah 2.19.1
Using globalid 1.0.0
Using activemodel 7.0.4
Using rspec 3.12.0
Using debug 1.7.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.4
Using net-smtp 0.3.3
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using net-imap 0.3.2
Using activejob 7.0.4
Using net-pop 0.1.2
Using activerecord 7.0.4
Using actionview 7.0.4
Using actionpack 7.0.4
Using mail 2.8.0
Using actioncable 7.0.4
Using actionmailer 7.0.4
Using activestorage 7.0.4
Using railties 7.0.4
Using actiontext 7.0.4
Using actionmailbox 7.0.4
Using rails 7.0.4
Installing pg 1.4.6 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectFolder/.bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.4.6/ext
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/bin/ruby -I /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0 extconf.rb
**--with-pg-config\=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config**
Calling libpq with GVL unlocked
Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-gvl-unlock
    --disable-gvl-unlock
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
extconf.rb:40:in `popen': No such file or directory - /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config (Errno::ENOENT)
    from extconf.rb:40:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectFolder/.bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.4.6 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectFolder/.bundle/ruby/3.1.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/3.1.0/pg-1.4.6/gem_make.out

  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:102:in `run'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:28:in `build'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `build_extension'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:205:in `block in build_extensions'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:202:in `each'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:202:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:843:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:207:in `install'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing pg (1.4.6), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  pg
```

I also noticed this line : **--with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config**
Where is a concern because I am using Postgres App version (15 or 15.2 or latest) all according to the commands below.

I expect that when running the `rails s` command I should be able to start up the rails server. I had this working fine until last week. I download postgres via hombrew. Since I was not able to fix it I uninstalled postgres via homebrew and started using the postgressApp. Eventually got the $PATH configuration working but then the pg installation keeps failing.

Results when I run the following commands:

```
$ psql

psql (15.2)


$ which pg_config

/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config\


$ echo $PATH

/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/username/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin


$ find /Applications -name pg_config

/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/bin/pg_config


$ gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config


Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-1.4.6
1 gem installed


$ cd ~/.rbenv ; find . -name mkmf.log | grep pg`

./versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/3.1.0/pg-1.1.0/mkmf.log
./versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/3.1.0/pg-1.4.5/mkmf.log
./versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/3.1.0/pg-1.4.6/mkmf.log
./versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/2.7.0/pg-1.2.3/mkmf.log
```

So its clear that pg has successfully been installed but not sure know how to fix the following

**Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.**

Comment: If you need custom flags for a gem when installing, don't forget to set [bundler build options](https://bundler.io/v1.12/man/bundle-config.1.html) so `bundle` can install correctly as well.

Comment: @tadman I have reviewed the attache link. I'll give it a try in a couple hours. Are you sure this will resolve the `lack of necessary libraries and/or headers` which has been preventing the creation of the Makefile?

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using this flag:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

But later you say you have Homebrew installed in:

```
/opt/homebrew
```

Which is where Homebrew is installed on Apple Silicon Macs. Likewise, you have the path:

```
./versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/
```

Which indicates arm64, not x86_64.

My suggestion is that you remove Postgres.app and instead [install Postgres through Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgresql@15):

```bash
brew install postgresql@15
```

Then remove any custom flags you're using for compiling the gem and use the defaults.

Comment: I followed the steps above yet still having an issue with pg. 

Still having an issue with `Calling libpq with GVL unlocked Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.`

Comment: `/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config` is the wrong directory. It should be in `/opt/homebrew/bin/pg_config` -- note that it's `/opt/homebrew` where Brew installs software. I would frankly be shocked if the path `/usr/pgsql-9.3` even existed on your system. You very likely have not undone the things you did that led you to this point. Get back to a clean start and try again.

Comment: Figure it out. Thanks. I simply ran `brew install libpq` and followed the steps to add it to my PATH followed but `bundle install`